# Difference between 대해서 and 대한?

Tags: word-choice, difference, word-usage

I know there that:
~ 에 대해서 + noun or verb

~ 에 대한 + only noun

but when I used: "인터뷰에 **대해서** 소식이 없어요?"

my friend edited it like this:" 인터뷰에 **대한** 다른 소식 없나요?"

While due to the above rule, I have used 대해서 correctly.
Is there any other difference between these two words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

대한 is a modifier, whereas 대해서 acts as a conjunction.

so -에 대한 will always be followed by a noun, whereas -에 대해서 should be followed by a verb phrase (the verb phrase might begin with a noun, but should end with a verb).
In the sentence "인터뷰에 대한 소식이 없어요", "인터뷰에 대한" **describes** 소식 - we can say "news about the interview".  If we can say "Noun about such and such", it is much more natural to use -에 대한.

On the other hand, if we want to focus on the action about something, we'll use 에 대해서:

> 그 문제에 대해서 많이 생각했어요 (I thought a lot about that problem)

Answer (score 4):

'대해', '대하여', '대해서' are all completely interchangeable.

'대하여' is a inflectional form of the verb '대하다' by affixing '-여' to the stem '대하-' and '대해', '대해서' are contracted forms of '대하여', '대하여서'.

'[-ㄴ](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6552900)' is used to change a verb to [adnominal phrase 관형어](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=1064730&cid=40942&categoryId=32978). '관형어' is close to 'adjective' and that's why it is natural and appropriate for a noun to follow it.

"인터뷰에 대해서 (어떤) 소식이 없어요?" is perfectly grammatical. It literally means "Is there any news about the interview?"

"인터뷰에 대한 다른 소식 없나요?" is also perfectly grammatical. It literally translates to "Is there **other** news about the interview?"

The only difference between the two is the latter is used when you heard one or more pieces of news about the interview before and ask if there are other pieces of news related with the interview.

I am not sure why your friend edited your question, but the latter sounds more idiomatic than the former. Please show this answer to your friend and ask him/her if my answer makes sense.

Comment: That is the case "when you heard one or more pieces of news about the interview before and ask if there are other pieces of news related with the interview. " I thought it may be some problem with  대해서  so she changed it to  대한. Thanks!

Comment: @Hanna Always my pleasure. Only your friend knows why the sentence was edited that way. :-)